# Weapon clash: Is it possible to knock bullets out of the air with an attack?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I know that you can't just guard projectiles, but is it possible to slice a bullet in half using a regular attack?

EDIT: Despite what the manual says, you CAN just guard projectiles such as bullets and arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to deflect bullets using a regular attack. The result is the same as a weapon clash for the person being shot at.

I just confirmed this in training using Mitsurugi and Ezio's `B+K` unblockable shot from a great distance. Deflecting bullets works with either `A` or `B`, but not `K` (understandably). I think it generally follows the same rules as weapon clash.

What's interesting is that despite what it says in the manual, **just guard** can be used to block bullets as well.

Answer (score 1):

Guys, check this out. 
I filmed this and it is completely possible to cut a bullet.